# How does mutex work in multicore systems?

Tags: multithreading, mutex

In single-processor systems, mutexes are atomic operations, meaning no other thread can change the mutex while an instruction is executing.
However, in a multicore system, what happens if two threads attempt to change the mutex value simultaneously while they are working on separate cores ?

[Instruction set of mutex from operating systems book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSNzb.png)